# Python Django arrangement of posts within a category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I wanted some help from you, if it is possible, I am working in Django, I was trying to arrange the posts in the template, but without success, so far I have displayed the posts in the template. order_by ('-data_e_postimit') the same I want to function in posts Within a category.

```
class LajmetListView(ListView):
    model = Kategori
    model = Lajmet
    template_name = 'main/lajme-home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'lajmet'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LajmetListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['lajmet'] = Lajmet.objects.order_by('-data_e_postimit')
        context['trilajmet'] = Kategori.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['katego'] = Kategori.objects.all()
        return context


<div class="slick_slider">
          {% for lajmet in trilajmet.lajmet_set.all %}
          {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
          <div class="single_iteam"> <a href="{% url 'lajme-detail' lajmet.slug %}"> <img src="media/{{lajmet.fotografit}}" alt=""></a>
            <div class="slider_article">
              <h2><a class="slider_tittle" href="{% url 'lajme-detail' lajmet.slug %}">{{lajmet.titulli}}</a></h2>
              <p>{{lajmet.detajet|safe}}</p>
              <p>{{lajmet.data_e_postimit|date:"F d, Y H:i"}}</p>

            </div>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your question, but as far as I saw your code, here are some problems and suggestions:

- You can only have one `model` attribute in your view, which means your second assignment of `model = Lajmet` will override your first one, this `model = Kategori` will not work.
  You may want to remove the `Kategori` one, remember that the `ListView` is **listing multiple instances of a corresponding model**, in this case, your are listing your `lajmet`.
- As it is a `ListView`, usually we use a plural form `context_object_name`, for example use `posts` for `Post` model.
- If you want to filter posts in a certain category, do it in your view instead of in your template:

```py
class LajmetListView(ListView):
    model = Lajmet
    template_name = 'main/lajme-home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'lajmets' # not sure about the plural form in your language
    paginate_by = 5 # set pagination if necessary
    # queryset = Lajmet.objects.filter(katego='trilajmet')
    # ordering = '-data_e_postimit'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['lajmets'] = Lajmet.objects.filter(katego='trilajmet').order_by('-data_e_postimit') 
        # or just move to the 'queryset' and 'ordering' attribute, 
        # either will work the same, your 'context' variable actually will include
        # a queryset of 'lajmet' and the order if you define them as attributes
        context['trilajmet'] = Kategori.objects.get(pk=1) # do you need 'trilajmet' in your template?
        context['katego'] = Kategori.objects.all() # do you need all categories?
        return context
```

Then in your template you can simply do:

```html
{% for lajmet in lajmets %}
{# ... #}
{% endfor %}
```

Here are some other suggestions may or may not relate to your requirements.

- Use a **context processor** to add common context variables. If the template variable of categories is used in multiple views, you may consider implementing a customized **context processor** and add it to your settings. This will help you to avoid repeating yourself on adding `katego` in every view. Check [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/django-quick-tips-context-processors-da74f887f1fc) or official doc for more details
- If you want to implement a filter function on your list view, try to rewrite `get_ordering` and `get` method of `ListView`
- If you like to dive deeper into how to customize those methods, I suggest reading the source code of `ListView` so you can have a better understanding.

Hope you can figure it out, good luck!

Comment: Thank You very much for the solution and this well explained